# Is the HMM module in scikit learn reliable?

Tags: scikit-learn, hidden-markov-models

I read that it had some numerical stability errors and I was wondering if it's ready for prime time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question can not be generally answered.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to collect this information here for someone who may crash here searching on google.

As stated in the documentation of *scikit* the module for Hidden Markov Models is now deprecated:

`Warning The sklearn.hmm module has now been deprecated due to it no longer matching the scope and the API of the project. It is scheduled for removal in the 0.17 release of the project.`

Now is working as a solo project that you can find in github:

https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn

All the best,

Answer (score 1):

Numerical stability issues can be detected easily if they happen: you will get `NaN` values in the output and/or the fitted parameters of the model.